# Why does field.errors display duplicate error messages from clean() method in Django form?

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

Whether I use `clean()` or `clean_initial_ph()` I get duplicate error messages.

[image]

Also if I iterate over form fields:

```
   {% for field in form %}
        {{ field|as_crispy_field }}
        {% if form.errors %}
            {% for error in field.errors %}
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
                {% endif%}          
        {% endfor %}
```

or list the fields and errors manually:

```
...
            {{ form.initial_ph|as_crispy_field }}
            {{ form.initial_ph.errors }}
...
```

I still get the duplicate error messages (albeit different styling for the larger one).

[image]

I followed the [validation guidelines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/#raising-validationerror). For example in `clean_initial_ph()` my validation looks like this:

```
    def clean_initial_ph(self):
        initial_ph = self.cleaned_data['initial_ph']
        if initial_ph:
            if initial_ph < 0:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_("PH must be above 0."), code = 'negative_intial_ph')
        return initial_ph
```

I have another validation on some time fields in `clean()` which does not display duplicate error messages:

```
# Assuming clean_initial_ph is commented out
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        pump_time = cleaned_data.get("pump_time")
        disposal_time = cleaned_data.get("disposal_time")
        incorptime = cleaned_data.get("incorptime")
        initial_ph = cleaned_data.get("initial_ph")
        disposal_ph = cleaned_data.get("disposal_ph")
        if pump_time and disposal_time: # DOES NOT DISPLAY DUPLICATE ERROR MESSAGES
            if pump_time >= disposal_time:
                self.add_error('pump_time','Pump time must be prior to disposal time.')
                self.add_error('disposal_time','Disposal time must be after to pump time.')
            if incorptime:
                if incorptime <= disposal_time:
                    self.add_error('incorptime','Incorp time must be after to disposal time.')
        if initial_ph: # DOES DISPLAY DUPLICATE ERROR MESSAGES
            if initial_ph < 0:
                self.add_error('initial_ph','PH must be above 0.')
        if disposal_ph: # DOES DISPLAY DUPLICATE ERROR MESSAGES
            if disposal_ph < 0:
                self.add_error('disposal_ph','PH must be above 0.')
```

What's going on here? Any ideas welcome - thanks!

Comment: You are using both clean and clean_field_name methods in the same time? If you validate in clean_field_name method you shouldn't validate again in clean and viceversa. Actually, in clean you should validate only when you need more than one fields to ensure the data integrity.

Comment: I am not actually using them at the same time - I just tried both options debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and found the solution: You have to "assign" the error message to a field in the `clean()` function:

```
raise ValidationError({"field_name": _("Invalid value")}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you should check if the field has errors, not the form.

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field|as_crispy_field }}
    {% if field.errors %} // not form
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif%}          
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for catching this - it did not fix my issue but is definitely the correct way to check for errors.

Comment: You are still getting duplicated error messages after checking for field.errors?

Comment: Yes - I changed form to field on that third line. And I still get duplicate errors. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your full code, including form definition and the view.? The only case when error messages are duplicated is when the same validator is used twice for the same field.